# Remove bottom corners when using 'Round Rectangle Tool'?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I use a 'Round Rectangle Tool' to create navigation bar (for website)..

How to remove two rounded corners at the bottom?

Once it has been removed then I can apply some style from blending options.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use either **Layer mask** directly in the layer or group the layer(s) and put layer mask into that group instead.

---

**Option 1. Layer mask in the layer.**

1. Select an area you want to hide with the Rectangular marquee tool.
2. Make sure you have the right layer ann hold down `alt` key while you click the Layer mask icon at the bottom of layer panel.

This way Layer styles will adapt the visible shape of the object.

[image]

---

**Option 2. Layer Mask in a group.**

1. `Do exactly the same thing as in Option 1. except select group when you click Layer mask icon.`

Putting Layer mask into a group will allow Layer styles to retain the initial area of the object.

This has some advantages at times. For example if you don't want shadow to start curving inwards right where the objects bottom starts or if you don't want to retain that bevel at the bottom.. etc..

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Lollero - Option 2 is definitively best option for me.  Just a quick question... If a button have red border and I use 'Option 2' method - I want bottom border to have a different color or add a shadow at the bottom - what is the solution to this?

Comment: @user791022 I'm not 100% sure what you mean with the shadow or more like what the shadow would be like, but border I would probably make with Gradient overlay with sharp edge ..or By making extra layer containing rectangle at the bottom of that button on top of the button layer an making a mask according to the button layer by `ctrl` clicking the layer thumbnail and making layer mask into that 'extra layer'. Thought depending on what kinda shadow you were talking about, this might not even be that good..

Answer (score 6):

### Option 3 - Use the shape layers and remove anchors.

[image: Shape Layers]

Comment: I think this method is preferable, because it maintains vector editablity. Another way to do it would be to draw a rounded rectangle, then a rectangle on top with Subtract from Shape (you could then combine shapes, if you wanted).

Comment: @MarcEdwards The reason why you'd prefer this method is not very valid reason considering my method maintains shape editability just as well. In fact, my method maintains the initial shape of the object, which may come in handy if you for example later on want to change all the corners rounded. All you have to do is hide the Layer mask rather than make a new rounded rectangle, which is what you would have to do using this method. On another note: The other method you mentioned that you might use is a method that would be my second choice.

Comment: @Lollero ... I disagree. You'd have to redraw the rounded corners if you wish to alter anything but the height in your method. The rounding of corners is never retained by a layer mask. With the shape layer method, you simply grab a side and alter it. I much prefer working with a single shape layer, than working with multiple layers and masks. It simply makes file organization much easier. Save appearance as a style, then it's dead simple to create multiple objects with the same appearance without the need to edit masks and internal masked layers. You're making more work than is needed.

Comment: @Scott If Shape layer is given a Layer mask, how does it become less editable than it was before the Layer mask? You can still move points in a shape layer even if it has Layer mask. In my method the layer is shape layer from start to finish. Layer mask just blocks out the parts you don't want to be visible.

Comment: But in the mask method you've got multiple layers to edit. There's absolutely zero added benefit and additional edit effort. It works. But, for me, the layer mask is superfluous and unnecessary. You posted as if there's added benefit to the mask when editing - as if corners would remain rounded. That's just not true.

Comment: @Scott I'm beginning to think that one of us is not talking about photoshop and shape layers and layer masks. Only thing Layer mask does to the Shape layer is that it makes parts of it invisible. Those invisible parts are not in any way deleted or uneditable like you seem to believe. http://tinyurl.com/cht6y27

Comment: @Joonas and Scott please continue the discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner).